# Function Specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I try to figure out what is difference between this to function.

First one is template function for adding to expression :

```
template <class T,class Y,class Z>
Z add(T t,Y y)
{
  return t+y;
}
```

Specialization_1 :

```
template<>
int add<int,int,int>(int t,int y)
{

    return t+y+10000;
}
```

Specialization_2 :

```
int add(int t,int y)
{

    return t+y+10000;
}
```

What difference is **between speciaization_1 and specialization_2** ?
Is it necessary to use template<> before declaration????

Comment: Template can be used with anyType
while your function works only with `int`

Comment: I know  why we have to use template but I asked about difference betweeen spec_1 and spec_2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differences between template specialization and overloading for functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511935/differences-between-template-specialization-and-overloading-for-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first is Specialization. the second is overloading.

the first will create a special varient of the template. and the second will create another function with the same name

Comment: SO when is better to use specialization over overloading ?

Comment: this may helphttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108033/template-specialization-vs-function-overloading

Answer (score 0):

I don't see interest in your first specialization. this is more useful for example:

```
template <typename T>
T add(T t,T y)
{
  return t+y+10000;
}
```

Now you can use this function add for many differents type.